# reCaptcha alternative

Tags: gratis, privacy, spam, captcha

I am looking for an open source, or privacy conscious alternative to reCaptcha. Or any other bot protection for web forms.

Preferably in PHP or JavaScript.

At a minimum, free and not Google.

Comment: If you omit the open-source requirement, [hCaptcha](https://hcaptcha.com/) is a great alternative to Google's reCAPTCHA. They [do](https://hcaptcha.com/privacy) collect some information, though.

Comment: @DavidRefoua be aware that they are currently advertising/astroturfing/spamming their services all around. I saw some posts on the SE network too (now removed).

Comment: @chrki Well that's obviously not nice, but at the time I suggested their services, I was impressed to see a non-Google alternative that actually was worth using. No idea if their services are still useful, though.

Answer (score 2):

Securimage, or http://www.phpcaptcha.org  is a great alternative that I recently found. Although I have not experienced its effectiveness. It is entirely self hosted open source, and runs in php and javascript. It is very user friendly and heavily customizable in appearance and function.